# pgfplots: tik labels missing and axis labels are inside plot

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I am having major trouble in getting pgfplots to work on my Ubuntu 14 System.
I am running the minimum example from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pgfplots/ and the result looks like the following.

[image]

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

according to `tex -version` I am using `TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)` and I will also post the part of my logfile that is created by `\listfiles` below. (btw, I tried various `compat=1.x` commands, but none of them changed anything)

```
*File List*
article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class  
size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
pgfrcs.code.tex
pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
dvips.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
pgfplots.sty    2013/10/03 v1.9 Data Visualization (1.9)
***********
```

Comment: Hi multigrid101, welcome to the site! How do you compile your document? Using `pdflatex`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint (and at that speed :) ) . I am compiling using a shortcut in vim which seems to be linked to the wrong compiler. Tried `pdflatex` from the command line and now everything is fine. So I was using the wrong compiler.

Comment: @Jake That should be the answer! :D